# Should I be pruning my chilli plants during a Sydney winter?

Tags: chili, winter, pruning

It's been an unseasonably cold winter this year in Sydney.

My chilli plants live outdoors. At the moment they are still alive, but most have lost most of their leaves.

Should I prune off the dead branches?

Should I do any other pruning before Summer kicks in?

Comment: Cold in Sydney means what, 4°C, 10°C?

Comment: Yes, sub 10°C. I think it dipped to around 5°C at night for a few days this winter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, don't prune now. If the weather has been colder than usual and still is, wait for signs of growth, then cut back. Cutting back when growth hasn't started and the weather is still cold could cause plant death, or at the least, any new growth forced by the pruning to be caught in a cold snap.